# MongoDB sum of all array size in document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

On MongoDB I have a collection like this: -

```
{
  org: "org",
  departments: [
    {
       name: "abc",
       employees: [
         { name: "number1" },
         { name: "number2" },
         { name: "number3" },
       ]
    },
    {
       name: "mno",
       employees: [
         { name: "number4" },
         { name: "number5" }
       ]
    },
    {
       name: "xyz",
       employees: [
         { name: "number6" },
         { name: "number7" }
       ]
    }
  ]
},{
  org: "xyz"....
}
```

How to find total employees in "org" by using aggregate?
expect result 
{ 
   org: "org",
   total_employees: 7 
},
{
  org: "xyz",
  total_employees: x
},....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the [**`$size`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html)(length) of the array by looping over `departments` array using [**`$map`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) aggregation and then can  [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) together all the array values

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": { 
    "total_employees": {
      "$sum": {
        "$map": { 
          "input": "$departments",
          "in": { "$size": "$$this.employees" }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**Output**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2b0Oh7vdB7T)

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "total_employees": 7
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) to get length of inner arrays and [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to sum those lengths:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
        total_employees: {
            $reduce: {
                input: "$departments",
                initialValue: 0,
                in: { $add: [ "$$value", { $size: "$$this.employees" } ]  }
            }
        }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kXRgk-gC3CY)